# How can you set the address of elements in an array to point to specific elements in another array?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-address

Let's say we have an array with 10 elements and we want to extract a 6-element sub-array from it that contains the first three items and the last three items. I don't want the extracted sub-array to be an independent array but I want its items to point to the same locations in memory as the corresponding items in the original array. How can I do that?

Comment: To start with, use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of arrays. Then it's easy to get the three last items no matter the size.

Comment: The problem with your question is, you did not select the right tool for the job to start with. Of course it could be done with arrays, but you would end up with impractical, fragile and probably inefficient code. I suggest you rephrase your question so that the answer could be more general and likely to be useful to other users as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array of pointers to point to the elements in the other one:

```
int a[10] = { 5, 3, 7, 4, 9, 2, 0, 3, 3, 6 };
int* b[6];
b[0] = &a[0];
b[1] = &a[1];
```

and so on. You have to be sure that `a` lives t least as long as `b`.

A more idiomatic solution might be to use a range type to hold a pointer to the first and one past the last elements of interest. The range would be iterable in the same way as a standard library container. See `boost.range` for example, or you can roll out a minimal and simple version using pointers as iterators. This would satisfy your use-case. For example:

```
struct range
{
  typedef const int* const_iterator;
  const_iterator begin() const {return begin_;}
  const_iterator end() const { return end_; }
  range(const int* begin, const int* end) : begin_(begin), end_(end) {}
  std::size_t size() const {return end_ - begin_ };
private:
  int* begin_;
  int* end_;
};
```

Then

```
int a[10] = { 5, 3, 7, 4, 9, 2, 0, 3, 3, 6 };
range b(&a[0], &a[3);
for (range::const_iterator i = b.begin(); i != b.end(); ++i)
  std::cout << *i << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: What if I have something like `int* b;` in my class and I want it to point to items of array `a`?

Comment: `int* b` is not an array, it is a pointer to int. So you would have to make it point to an array first, then do the same as in this example. But that is another story and different question.

Comment: @MohammadSanei What I said in my previous comment, except that the array will have to be dynamically allocated. In which case I would suggest you use a vector of pointers instead.

Comment: That would be tedious! I have written hundreds of lines of code using the pointer in my class! Is there a way to use dynamic allocation without using vectors? Doesn't placement new have anything to do with this?

Comment: @MohammadSanei if you want to learn about dynamic allocation of arrays, then post a question about it. I have answered the question you asked. Note that people will just tell you to use vectors.